# Topological sort of a graph- how can we find a contradiction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science

The topological sort of a graph can be considered as an order of its nodes along a horizontal line so that all the directed edges go from the left to the right.

How could we show that all the directed edges go fom the left to the right?

We suppose that it is:

[image]

Then it holds that $[d(w),f(w)] \subset [d(u),f(u)]$, right?

How could we find a contradiction?

PS:  d(u)  is the discovery time of the node u , the first time we visit it.
 f(u)  is the finishing time of the node  u , the time when it can be considered discovered.

We find these values using the  DFS  algorithm.

This the algorithm that it given for the topological sort:

```
TOPOLOGICALSORT(G)
1. Call DFS(G) to compute finishing times f(v),  for all v in V.
2. When a vertex is finished put it in front of a linked list.
3. return the linked list of vertices.
```

Comment: Any graph with a directed cycle would fail to have a topological sort.

Comment: Can a graph without a directed cycle always have a topological sort?

Comment: Yes, it can. Or am I wrong? @LaarsHelenius

Comment: Every arrangement of vertices in a transitive graph is a topological sort.

Comment: A ok... But how could we find a contradiction?

Comment: Sorry about the string of comments, I'm driving and the voice-to-text feature is limited. I am not sure how you would identify these properties algorithmically. Perhaps you could look at these properties rather than directly at your problem to think about ways of identifying topological sorts.

Comment: Hint: think about how DFS behaves differently when it encounters a contradiction.